# get the length of first column in csv

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm fairly new to python. I'm looking for the best way to get the length of the first column in a csv list. My tryouts always ended up with the length of a row or the length of the string items in the fields. But I'm just looking for a way to get the length of the first column.

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
    print map(len, row)
```

Comment: you mean, you want to count rows in 1st column?

Comment: yes exactly. thats the plan

Comment: and if there is a way to leave out the blank rows as well... but thats an additional thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip` function to get an iterable object from columns:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    first_col_len = len(next(zip(*reader)))
```

Note: In python 2.X `zip` returns a list so you can just use indexing to get the first column:

```
first_col_len = len(zip(*reader)[0])
```

Or as a more optimized approach you can use `itertools.izip()` to get an iterator result, and then just use `next()`.

Comment: Many thanks! In fact I was trying out the zip function before, but I could not get it run.