# length of the first column in csv

Tags: python, csv

I am new in python. I would like to ask what is the optimal way of getting length on the first column of csv file in python ? I tried this, but got this error:

```
File "C:/Projekty/valispace_api/CreatingCvs.py", line 6, in <module>
    first_col_len = len(next(zip(*reader)))
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Thanks

```
import csv
with open('export_U43V_WIRKNETZ.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    first_col_len = len(next(zip(*reader)))
print(first_col_len)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get the length of first column in csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41565007/get-the-length-of-first-column-in-csv)

Comment: I think what you did should give you the length of the first row if anything. If you want to know the length of the first column you'd need to read the full file, as it is read row by row.